# How to work with weighted automata dataset for Keras Regression

Tags: python, keras, regression, automata

I'm trying to work with a dataset for a weighted automata.
The dataset structure is

```
/dataset
 /train
   ID_Weigth.txt
 /test
   ID_Weight.txt
```

So I basically have a .txt-file with a simple string. Before I can try to figure out the details regarding the regression itself to predict the weight of a string based on my data, I need to prepare my data. Currently I'm trying to use the function `text_dataset_from_directory` but I don't know where to go from there with preparing that data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out an easier way to do it.

Instead of using `text_dataset_from_directory` I changed my dataset.
I now have a .csv-file where I have my weight and the word next to it. I can read that into np-arrays and input them into Keras.